# Prevent change in position of div with height increase

Tags: javascript, html, css

[codepen](https://codepen.io/cjreads665/pen/wvqgayG)

```
form{
    min-height: 50vh;
    transition: all 0.7s linear;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    border: 0 2px 0 0 solid black;
    width: 20rem;
    padding: 10%;
    margin:auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #e9ac67;
    position: relative;
}
input{
    height: 2rem;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
label{
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.sug-city{
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0.5rem;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
li{
    border: black 2px solid;
    margin:0
}
```

Whenever the suggestion list appears, the height increases(which was expected), but the position of the form also changes. I want the height to grow *vertically downwards* and not upwards. Think of how Google's search bar works. That's the end result I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put your listelement inside the same container - so expanding the list would also expand everything.

You can put your listelement outside and/or give it an absolute position.
Minimal changes can be found here: [codepen](https://codepen.io/coyer/pen/KKvapbv)

Basically I wrapped the inputfield in a relative-positioned wrapper to keep that position; then I changed ul to `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 1):

### Try This

---

```
ul {
    max-height: 250px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is because your body's `display:flex` and you have applied `justify-content:space-evenly`. Which automatically adjust the available space between elements. When the suggestions' list appears, it increases the size of your select element and occupies more space on the screen which eventually appears to move upwards.

Modify you `CSS` like this, this will solve your problem.

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative; //So you can specify childrens' absolute position
    min-height: 100vh;font-family: 'Urbanist', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #051937, #4d295a, #983461, #d2524d, #e98c27);
}

form {
    min-height: 50vh;
    transition: all 0.7s linear;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    border: 0 2px 0 0 solid black;
    width: 20rem;
    padding: 10%;
    margin:auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: #e9ac67;
}

header {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is better use another Units for declaring height.
"vh" unit can make some problems specially in mobile devices.

```
 and also use 
 ul{
   overflow-y: scroll;
 }
```

Comment: Isn't vh recommended though? Or should I use rem?

Comment: you know i think for height it is not necessary to set any unit, because it is flexible by it self , if you wanna use unit use rem and for "vh" just use in desktop displays with writing media queries . hopefully it makes sense;